# Inconsistent vertical alignment of two inner divs (caused by multi-select?)

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, multi-select

Can someone please explain why the first inner `<div>` in this example is aligned to the top of the containing `<div>`, while the second is aligned to the bottom of the same container?

[image: http://jsfiddle.net/CmhV2/3/]

I've included the code below, and it's also on JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/CmhV2/3/.

CSS:

```
 div {                                                                          
   border: #000 1px solid                                                       
 }                                                                                                                                                         
 .inner {                                                                       
   display: inline-block;                                                                                                                             
 }
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"> 
          <select name="project_filter"
                  multiple="multiple"
                  style="width:120px;height:29px">
              <option value="1">Project 1</option>
              <option value="2">Project 2</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="inner" style="line-height:29px">
          <input id="projects_breakout"
                 name="projects_breakout"
                 type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="projects_breakout">View by Project</label>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In case you're wondering about the "line-height:29px" on the right-hand `<div>`, that's my attempt (based on "Method 2" in [this oft-quoted article](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/)) to get the checkbox+label to vertically align with the middle of the multi-select, which (for reasons I won't detail here) I've determined needs to be 29px tall.

But that article's advice does me no good if I can't get the two `<div>`s to align with one another in the first place!

Of course, I *can* make them align by adding "position:relative;top:-3px" to the right-hand `<div>`'s CSS -- which is just hackery of the most offensive sort.

Still, as a stopgap until I have a proper answer, I'm swallowing my pride and doing just that. But I'd much rather understand what's going on (i.e., why is the multi-select forcing the left-hand `<div>` to the top of the container?), and use that understanding to solve the problem the *right* way.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as adding `vertical-align: bottom` to the `div`s:

```
div {                                                                          
   border: #000 1px solid;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CmhV2/8/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align` to `.inner`:

```
.inner {                                                                       
    display: inline-block;        
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mJkQ/

The cause has to do with the fact that the default `vertical-align` is `baseline`.  For non-text element this means that there is a small gap added below the element as there is space below the baseline of text to allow letters like "g" and "y" to hang below the baseline.

Comment: I'm sorry, that explanation isn't making sense to me: why would a "non-text element" have letters like "g" and "y"? After all, it's *non-text*. What am I missing here?

Comment: The non-text element doesn't have letters at all.  But it is aligned with the "text baseline" unless you change that.  The reason for the space is that there is space below the baseline for letters.  Whether or not there are letters, the baseline always has that space below it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, comparing their position while one has a `line-height` and the other doesn’t isn’t fair, right? So let’s add the same `line-height` to the first `div` as well.

Now you see that there’s space left *under* the `select` element, and the first `div` is actually higher than the second one – why is that?
Well, because the `select` element is aligned on the text baseline – so let’s fix that with `vertical-align:bottom` … and both divs have the same height, and checkbox and label text are vertically centered in regard to the select: http://jsfiddle.net/CmhV2/10/

Comment: Well, your answer seems consistent with that of @James Montagne, but I gotta say, I'm having trouble with the assertion that "the `select` element is aligned on the text baseline." See http://jsfiddle.net/CmhV2/12/. There, with some text added for comparison, and pretty much all the styling ripped out, the bottom of the `select` is a good 3 or 4px below the text baseline (it's in fact below *all* the descenders). It would be hard for me to accept either of your answers with this rather glaring counterexample out there,

Comment: @Hephaestus - You are right. Although the given explanations are normally right for these kind of gaps, it's not the reason in this case. Unfortunately, what's happening is different for different browsers. If we inspect the select element in FF, we find that it is by default aligned `text-bottom`. So it aligns with the text bottom of the line-box, not with its baseline. The gap below is caused by the below half-leading of the label text which pushes the bottom of the label below the line box's text-bottom if it is sufficiently large. Chrome works in a different that that is harder to inspect.